# Create a CSS rule that only applies to IMG tags with a png or jpg format

Tags: css

I want to create a CSS rule that applies a rule to img tags, but only if the src attribute points to a jpg image. Images in the png format should be excluded from this rule and I do not want to use Javascript.

The attribute selector is a where I started looking however it only applies the styling when I can specify the whole attribute's value and doesn't help apply the style to all images that have the .jpg extension.

```
img[src="https://example.com/image.jpg"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0px #636363;
}
```

Can I extend this to only apply the rule based on image extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to solve my problem by adding a dollar symbol before the equals symbol.

```
img[src$=".jpg"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0px #636363;
}
```

This basically tells the browser to apply the styling to any images where the src tag ends with .jpg.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out how to solve my problem by adding a dollar symbol before the equals symbol.

```
img[src$=".png"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0px #636363;
}
```

This basically tells the browser to apply the styling to any images where the src tag ends with .png.

I wrote about this with more [examples of using CSS3 attribute values here](https://andyp.dev/posts/css-attribute-selector-css-styling-based-on-image-extension).

Comment: If I understood well the OP, he wants the opposite: `img[src$=".jpg"]`.